# Android ImageView Gesture/DoubleTap not firing

Tags: android, events, imageview, gesture

Ok, so I have this setup

ScrollView
  HorizontalScrollView
    ImageView

I am trying to capture the doubleTap on the Image View.. my code looks like the following:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewID);

iv.setImageDrawable(iv.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.someimage));
// Gesture detection
detector = new GestureDetector(this,new SimpleOnGestureListener(){

    //new myGestureClass());

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("SINGLE TAP");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DOUBLE TAP");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DOUBLE TAP EVENT");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

});

View.OnTouchListener gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("TOUCH!" +event);
        if (detector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;                 
        }   
        return false;
        }
    };

iv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Yet the overridden tap methods never get called... The onTouch does get called but the detector.onTouchEvent(event) that should be tying my events to the touch event, never ever calls my overRidden methods.... So, what the heck am I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override onDown method and return true. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

Hope this help.

Comment: Wow, thanks.. I don't think I would have EVER found that one. Why would SimpleGestureListener return FALSE by default on that event if it is needed to feed up to the other events.