# double tap gesture is not called when I double tap a view in my activity

Tags: android

I implemented a gesture listener that listens to double tap and single tap events now the problem is that it is being called when I double tap the screen but it is not called when I double tap a functional view like a clickable button.
Thanks for your help.

I think that the button consumes the double tap, if that is the case what should I do?

Comment: There are so many similar posts here, did you check them out? For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042522/doubletap-detection-on-android-view-component, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611044/android-imageview-gesture-doubletap-not-firing

Comment: @yakobom do you have any idea on how to bind the detector of gestures to any view , so that when I double tap a view it will respond to the double tap?

Comment: In the examples I gave it is shown how to bind it. You do not need to bind it to each view, just make sure you implement onDown as shown there

Answer (score 0):

Check this site, it is a great tutorial about gestures in general, and for your case specifically it covers onDoubleTap method in step 5.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-introduction-to-gestures--mobile-2239